# Bind two ng-model in select angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is their a way to bind two ng-model in a select tag? To further explain this I will share some of my code

I have this dynamic input buttons, where if a user wishes to add a new option. Note I used two property opt.id & opt.text

```
<div ng-repeat="opt in q.options">
   <label><span>{{opt.id}}.</span></label>
   <input type="text" ng-model="opt.text" placeholder="Add new possible answer here.">
   <a ng-click="q.options.splice($index,1)"><i class="icon-remove-sign icon-large"></i> </a>
</div>
```

then I reused the q.options to display the ids in a select tag.

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in q.answer">
 <div>
    <select ng-model="answer.id" ng-options="c.id as c.id for c in q.options"></select>
    <a ng-click="q.answer.splice($index,1)"><i class="icon-remove-sign icon-large"></i></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

With this I was able to recreate the option ids and set the value ng-model="answer.id" to my controller but I also need the opt.text to set it to answer.text to be also fetch from my controller then pass it to my api call. I don't want to create another select tag for it.

added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/si_dean_ako/3UFAf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="select[$index]" ng-options="c.id for c in q.options" 
ng-change="change(answer,select[$index])"></select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.select = {};

$scope.change = function(o,v){      
    o.id = v.id;
    o.text = v.text;
}
```

Comment: tried what you suggested, it did saved but not what I expect. Now the response is like this: {id: { id: "a", text: "test"}, text: ""}. It should just have {id: "a", text: "test"}.

Comment: Change `ng-model="answer.id"` to `ng-model="answer"` and see if that is what you want.

Comment: tried, when saved gave me {id: "", text: ""} and also even though I select letter "a" when click it return to blank option.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or update your question to share the contents of `q`?

Comment: sorry, first time setting up in jsfiddle but here: http://jsfiddle.net/si_dean_ako/3UFAf/

Comment: it worked!. haven't really thought of this. Thank you again CodeHater. (bow)